# Is there a software to automatically copy the contents of a USB drive when connected?

Tags: windows, android, file-management, file-synchronization, usb

Specifically an android phone.

I want it to run in the background, and when an android phone is connected, it should copy its contents to a directory. Is there anything like it? I tried  USB SPY v1.3 and "Secret USB Copier", but they don't work properly.